# number of nonnegative integer solutions of linear equation $ x + y + z = n$, where $x\le y\le z$

Tags: combinatorics

I know the answer for the cases where I can have all possible values which will be given by $(n+k-1)C(k-1)$ but I don't know how to reduce it to the given constraints.

Comment: Why not try stars and bars? You have n stars and have to use 2 bars to split them. The first can cover a maximum of n/3 stars and the second can separate another n/3 stars or less.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan This problem has the added constraint that $x \leq y \leq z$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I added to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the restricted partition number $p_3(n)$.  This is the number of ways to divide $n$ into three integral pieces without regard to order.  For every such arrangement, you would assign $x$ to a minimal value of that triple, $z$ to a maximal value, and $y$ to the remaining value.

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) helpfully notes at (66) that $p_3(n)=\left[\frac{n^2}{12}\right]$, where the square bracket indicates rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: why there is 12 in the denominator?